# Is this sentence missing a relative pronoun?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> At later lessons we would be given a printed slip of paper entitled “Search the Scriptures,“ which was sent to the school by whatever national authority supervised the teaching of religion. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=8kgjU4wbM5oC&pg=PA2&dq=at%20later%20lessons%20we%20would%20be%20given%20a%20printed%20slip&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGhtXy4PTeAhUI2lMKHRosCFkQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=at%20later%20lessons%20we%20would%20be%20given%20a%20printed%20slip&f=false))

This sentence strikes me as ungrammatical and missing the relative pronoun "which/that" that should follow "national authority". Shouldn't it be like this?

> At later lessons we would be given a printed slip of paper entitled “Search the Scriptures,“ which was sent to the school by whatever national authority **that** supervised the teaching of religion.

Comment: Which is referring to the paper, not to the authority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of "whatever" changes the dynamic. If "whatever" had been "the", then you would be correct and the sentence would have to be:

> by **the** national authority **which** supervised the teaching of religion

But "whatever + noun" is functioning as a relative pronoun here, and so the sentence is correct as it is. Here's another example:

> Please put me in touch with whatever person sent me that email.

Comment: Yes, this is a 'fused' relative construction. The fusion involves "whatever national authority" (where "whatever" is a determinative) which serves simultaneously as head of the larger NP and as the _wh_ phrase at the beginning of the relative clause.

Comment: I would have called **whatever** an *indeterminative*.